# Page loading problem in production environment

Tags: visualforce, performance, production

we have implemented a visualforce page that displays 500 records along with images and map it is loading properly in sandbox but in production it is loading very slow.please see my page screenshot below.[image]

Can anyone help me, how to resolve these loading issue.

Comment: are you displaying 500 records all together?

Comment: yes we are displaying max of 500 records using pagination

Comment: Have you checked your view state size? Post your controller and vf page code

Comment: I guess you are using jquery plugin or something for pagination ?

Comment: Hi Himanshu,
actually my problem is page loading issue in production not in sandbox,if there is an issue with view state or code means load issue should occur in both sandbox and prod also(stage is loading and displaying data fine) are you getting my problem

Comment: Hi Ratan,we used JavaScript for pagination

Comment: ok if you are thinking that this issue comes because of sandbox and production different environment then you are wrong. This may be because of your image size that is causing.. We always prefer to use apex pagination because using apex pagination you    will able to display only few records at a time in vf page. It will not load all the images at a time like your javascript pagination. I think if you go with apex pagination then your issue can be solved permanently.

Comment: Yes you are right but initially we are loading only 10 images not all,whenever we scrolling down we are concatenating another 10 record images using pagination ..

Comment: @ncmouli when page load your are getting are all 500 images but showing 10. it means all 500 images present in vf page and only displaying 10. that is the reason for slow loading

Comment: i understand ur point. But those 500 images are not images...they are image urls...ie a string value....once it get pasted in <a> tag it becomes image. also those images belongs to a third party site

Answer (score 4):

Performance problems are best tackled by first gathering evidence and then using that evidence to identify the root cause and so hopefully the fix.

There are 3 tools I suggest you use and in this order:

- the [Network](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/network-performance/resource-loading?hl=en) tab of your browsers Developer Tools that presents how long it takes each piece of information to arrive in the browser and the sequence they arrive
- the Developer Console's [timeline feature](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Guide_to_Application_Performance_Profiling_in_Force.com) that organises the server debug log timestamps into overview tables and shows the breakout between the database, Apex controller code and Visualforce
- the Developer Console's [query plan tool](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000199003) that lets you check how the queries are being executed on the server

Start by running the tools in production and run them in the sandbox as needed to identify the differences.